# Play recorded video inside application in iOS

Tags: objective-c

I am doing chat application. I want to play a video as whatsapp do. I am using MPMoviePlayer for that but i am not able to make it as whats app did. If any one have an idea to do that please help me .

```
playerViewController =[[MPMoviePlayerCont‌​roller alloc] initWithContentURL:m‌​ovie_Url]; 
playerViewController‌​.shouldAutoplay = YES; 
playerViewController‌​.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.‌​view.frame.size.width‌​, self.view.frame.size‌​.height); 
[playerViewControlle‌​r prepareToPlay]; 
[playerViewControlle‌​r play]; 
[[playerViewControll‌​er view]setCenter:CGPoi‌​ntMake(self.view.fram‌​e.size.width/2.0f, self.view.frame.size‌​.height/2.0f)]; 
[self.view addSubview:playerVie‌​wController.view];
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code you have written, what you wish it to do and what it is doing instead.

Comment: playerViewController  =[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movie_Url];
    playerViewController.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    playerViewController.view.frame     =  CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [playerViewController prepareToPlay];
    [playerViewController play];
    [[playerViewController view]setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2.0f, self.view.frame.size.height/2.0f)];
    [self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];   I am using that code to play a video inside app.

Comment: Please explain what you wish it to do and what it is doing instead.

Comment: I want to make same functioning as iPhone Gallery provide i.e when we record a video it save in to gallery and when we play it play with frames.I need the video playing part.

Answer (score 0):

```
  AVAsset *avAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:movie_Url]];
    AVPlayerItem *avPlayerItem =[[AVPlayerItem alloc]initWithAsset:avAsset];
    AVPlayer *avPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithPlayerItem:avPlayerItem];
    avPlayerLayer =[AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:avPlayer];
       [avPlayer seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
    [avPlayerLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), (CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame)-64)/2)];
    [avPlayerLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:avPlayerLayer];
    [avPlayer play];

    UIButton *expandButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [expandButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"expand"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [expandButton addTarget:self action:@selector(videoPlayFull:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [expandButton setFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame)-40,CGRectGetMaxY(avPlayerLayer.frame)-40, 21, 21)];
    [self.view addSubview:expandButton];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But i am not able to get the seek bar like photo gallery gives. I mean in gallery, there is  a view in the bottom which shows the video frames.